# Spring Boot IBM Queue - Discover all Destinations

Tags: spring-boot, jms

I am writing a small spring boot application that is supposed to monitor queues on an external IBM Queue installation.

I am able to connect via MQXAQueueConnectionFactory, but I have not found a way to **discover all remote queues/destinations** on that Host programmatically. I don't want to add them fix in my code.

How can I get a list of all existing queues in order to add listeners? I have to mention that an access via REST-API is not possible because this feature has been disabled by the administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IBM MQ Programmable Command Formats](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=commands-introduction-mq-programmable-command-formats). If you installed the IBM MQ samples, the `tools/pcf/samples/PCF_DisplayActiveLocalQueues.java` gives you an idea for your use case.

Here is how I use it in my unit tests to find all the queues with messages:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQCFC;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.MQDataException;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.pcf.PCFMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.pcf.PCFMessageAgent;

public class MqUtils {

    public static void queuesWithMessages(MQQueueManager qmgr) {
        try {
            PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(qmgr);
            try {
                PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q);
                // NOTE: You can not use a queue name pattern like "FOO.*" together with
                // the "addFilterParameter" method. This is a limitation of PCF messages.
                // If you want to filter on queue names, you would have to do it in the
                // for loop after sending the PCF message.
                request.addParameter(CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");
                request.addParameter(CMQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQConstants.MQQT_LOCAL);
                request.addFilterParameter(CMQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH, CMQCFC.MQCFOP_GREATER, 0);
                for (PCFMessage response : agent.send(request)) {
                    String queueName = (String) response.getParameterValue(CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME);
                    if (queueName == null
                            || queueName.startsWith("SYSTEM")
                            || queueName.startsWith("AMQ")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Integer queueDepth = (Integer) response.getParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH);
                    // Do something with this queue that has messages
                }
            } catch (MQException | IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                agent.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (MQDataException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this should give you ideas how to configure the `MQQueueManager` (see also [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=managers-setting-up-mq-environment-mq-classes-java)):

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;

@Configuration
static class MQConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "disconnect")
    public MQQueueManager mqQueueManager() throws MQException {
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "the.host.com";
        MQEnvironment.port = 1415;
        MQEnvironment.channel = "xxx.CL.FIX";
        return new MQQueueManager("xxx");
    }
}
```

The chapter [Using with IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=package-using-mq-classes-jms) explains how you can use PCF messages in pure JMS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried, but got this exception:
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Beendigungscode '2', Ursache '2495'.

My setting:
  MQXAQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQXAQueueConnectionFactory();
        factory.setQueueManager("xxx");
        factory.setChannel("xxx.CL.FIX");
        factory.setPort(1415);
        factory.setTransportType(1);
        factory.setUseConnectionPooling(true);

The application is not running on the same machine as the server.

Comment: The error [2495: MQRC_MODULE_NOT_FOUND](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=codes-2495-09bf-rc2495-mqrc-module-not-found) means that native libraries are not found. This is because my code showed bindings mode. I will update my answer with client connection.