# How to get the number of consumers connected to a queue and also purge the queue with spring boot and ibm mq?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have the following method to get the queue depth but not sure how to get

1. number of consumers connected
2. purge the queue

I searched for some samples online but couldn't find.

```
public String getQueueDepth(String qname) {
    log.info("Getting queue depth for queue: " + qname);
    Integer totalUnreadMessages = 0;
    try {
        totalUnreadMessages = this.jmsTemplate.browse(qname, (session, browser) -> Collections.list(browser.getEnumeration()).size());
        String queueSizeStr = totalUnreadMessages == null ? "0" : String.valueOf(totalUnreadMessages);
        log.info("queueSizeStr: " + queueSizeStr);
        return queueSizeStr;
    } catch (JmsException ex) {
        log.error("Exception while fetching queue depth for qname {}: ", qname, ex.getMessage());
        return "FAIL";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at IBM MQ docs?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68160828/638413) answer helps to give you ideas.